# excluding some js file from minification in com.day.cq.widget.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I have a osgi config settings for config\com.day.cq.widget.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.xml

as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
    htmllibmanager.minify="{Boolean}true"
    htmllibmanager.debug="{Boolean}false"
    htmllibmanager.gzip="{Boolean}false"
    htmllibmanager.timing="{Boolean}false"
    />
```

however, I want some files not be minifyed. How can I do that ?

Comment: what is your usecase? Why wouldn't you want them minified? Anyway I can only think of referencing the specific file directly with a separate script tag instead of using the library manager

Comment: minification is needed for the files to be compress during execution. However, one is causing issue due to this.

Comment: Then I would rather check this file as it probably misses some ; at the end of a line or some other small thing that identifies a not so well written js file

Answer (score 0):

Since AEM 6.1 the [com.day.cq.widget.HtmlLibraryManager](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/widget/HtmlLibraryManager.html) interface and its implementation (com.day.cq.widget.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl) have been deprecated.

Instead, you should take a look at new [HtmlLibraryManager](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/ui/clientlibs/HtmlLibraryManager.html) interface.
The com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl implementation has interesting OSGi property "**htmllibmanager.excluded.path.list**" that might just be what you need.

Comment: htmllibmanager.excluded.path.list will exclude a path, how do you exclude a file ?

Comment: Can I use this feature for AEM6 SP2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I had read the solution to this problem in adobe forums, given by
[Sham HC](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__a4rq-the_yui_compressorc.html)

According to him, OOB not possible & you might need to implement own HTMLLibraryManager.  File daycare requesting feature pack.

If you have taken look at the below link you can take advantage of selector and at dispatcher OR linkrewriter remove .min for your request.

[New in AEM](http://aemfaq.blogspot.com/2013/05/whats-new-in-aem-html-library-manager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a **manual include** to be able to choose if minified or not. Nothing to change in your clientLibs. Using "htmllibmanager.excluded.path.list" doesn't work for me and I can read in documentation that `cq:ClientLibraryFolder` can not be exclude because it's hardly specified that's a clientLib.

To make something like this (css):

```
<sly data-sly-use.clientLib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html" data-sly-call="${clientLib.css @ categories='yourClientLib}" data-sly-unwrap/>
```

Use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/etc/designs/yourClientLib.css"/>
```

And to make this (js):

```
<sly data-sly-use.clientLib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html" data-sly-call="${clientLib.js @ categories='yourClientLib'}" data-sly-unwrap/>
```

Use:

```
<script src="/etc/designs/yourClientLib.js"></script>
```

So if you **don't want minification** your files will **end with ".js"** and if you want minification your files will end with ".min.js". Realy easy.